# parsing xml to json in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, json, xml-parsing

Am writing one small application to parse from XML to JSON object for iphone. can anyone tell me the availability of open source library present to do the parsing usnig objective-c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of open source solutions in objective-c to deal with JSON :

- JSONKit : https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit
- SBJson (aka json-framework) : https://github.com/stig/json-framework
- YAJL Framework : https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc

To deal with xml, you can use the default NSXMLParser class or some other solutions like some code I've posted here (DOM parser) :
[NSXMLParser retrieving wrong data from XML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821022/nsxmlparser-retrieving-wrong-data-from-xml-tags/5821167#5821167)

You can also check this page which will give you a good overview of available solutions for XML parsing (and an explaination of differences between SAX and DOM parsers) : http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a [json parser available for objective c](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) on github. Its very simple to use. You may have to write some additional code to provide input to the parser.

Answer (score 0):

I use [NSPropertyListSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from Apple to turn a Plist XML into a dictionary.  Then we just need to find something to go from dictionary to JSON.

The [json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) looks like a nice JSON generator.