# Xml To Json Conversion

Tags: android, iphone, xml, json, xml-parsing

Is there any API which can convert XML to JSON directly for Android and iPhone projects.

I want a perfect and direct solution/API which i can use in my android and iPhone apps. So that data in xml format can be directly converted in JSON format.

Any help would be appreciated. Please provide links to API(s) if any.

Comment: For IOS,check this : https://github.com/bcaccinolo/XML-to-NSDictionary

Answer (score 2):

For Android only I just released a "XML to JSON" Library for Android Studio.
It is easy to integrate with gradle, simple to use, and configurable.

**XmlToJson** is available on GitHub:

https://github.com/smart-fun/XmlToJson

enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

Since Android is Java and Xcode is object c i think you need to use a different library for each. This is a good example for android/java:

[How to Convert XML to JSON in Java](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/278-how-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-java/)

Im not that experienced with parsing XML in xcode but here is another question about that (and, it seems, a good answer):

[Parsing xml to json in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408758/parsing-xml-to-json-in-iphone)

Comment: Yes i need two different libs for both the tech as there is no comparison between iPhone and java.

Comment: Also i searching a library if any present which can take xml string as input and produce json as output. I don't want to do manual parsing of xml and create json from it. Is there any lib which can do this for me.

Comment: For java, the library that the first link is about should do it. For xCode you could use an XML-parser to parse the xml and then iPhone JSON Framework to create the JSON. Maybe thats not the simpliest thing but once youve done it, its done!