# Youtube API - How to retrieve json instead of xml?

Tags: objective-c, youtube-api

I want to load data from youtube api with JSON format instead of XML. This is my sources:

```
- (void) getFavoriteList{


    NSString* rawUrl = CONNECTION_GET_FAVORITE_LIST;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:rawUrl];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

   //create request header
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:[@" Bearer "  stringByAppendingString:[appDelegate userInfo].accessTokenYoutube ]];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"X-GData-Key" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key=%@",YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY]];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"alt" value:@"json"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"v" value:@"2"];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startAsynchronous];

    //register callback blocks.
    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSString* respondMessage = [request responseString];
        ParseData *parseData = [[ParseData alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *arrPlaylistVideos = [parseData allocVideo:respondMessage];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_GET_FAVORITE_VIDEOS_SUCCESS object:arrPlaylistVideos];
    }];
    [request setFailedBlock:^{
        NSString* respondMessage = [[request error] localizedDescription];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_GET_FAVORITE_VIDEOS_FAILED object:respondMessage];
    }];

    [request release];
}
```

I set the alt = json but Youtube always returns xml data. Did I make any mistake here?

NOTE: Please don't tell me that I should use Gdata-ObjectiveC-Client. It very very complicated and I hate to use it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to add alt=json in the request URL as a query string and not in the request Header.

Answer (score -1):

You can parse xml by NSXMLParser. Or you can find a xml to JSON lib easily. I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408758/parsing-xml-to-json-in-iphone) will be help.